# Opening profile site causes unexpected error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile-service, central-administration

I face this kind of problem in our client which use SharePoint 2010.
Seems like UserProfileService works fine and all profiles are up to date and synced with AD.

One person profile is causing the error during opening profile site (`/person.aspx?accountname=DOMAIN/USERNAME`).

[image: unexcpected error]

Anyone have any ideas where are the problem?

I also have checked ULS log and this is what it say :

> UserProfile.PersonalSite Exception while loading site 'https://mojawitryna/profile/mlempert/': System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki. (Wyjątek od HRESULT: 0x80070003)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, Int32& plSiteFlags, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, Int32& plSiteFlags, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWebPublic()     w Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_ID()     w Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.get_PersonalSite()
>
> PortalSiteMapProvider was unable to fetch requested node at URL: /, message: System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki. (Wyjątek od HRESULT: 0x80070003), stack trace:    w Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, Int32& plSiteFlags, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, Int32& plSiteFlags, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWebPublic()     w Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_ID()     w Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CacheManager.<.ctor>b__0(SPSite newSite)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CommonUtilities.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()     w Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2()     w Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CommonUtilities.RunWithElevatedSite(SPSite siteNonElev, Boolean allowUnsafeUpdates, ElevatedSiteProcessor callWithElevatedSite)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CacheManager..ctor(SPSite site)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CacheManager.GetManager(SPSite site, Boolean useContextSite, Boolean allowContextSiteOptimization)     w Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider.get_ObjectFactory()     w Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider.FindSiteMapNode(String rawUrl, SPWeb currentContext)

Comment: OK I figured out what was wrong. In Application Managment > Application Managment Service > User Profile Service > Users > Users Profile Managment :

Comment: I find the user that his profile site cause the error. What I did was "Edit my profile" and edit field "redirectoion public site" where was : http://mysite/ and put there full adres like :  http://mysite/profile/username and it work fine.